# dot instead of slash in c# file path

Tags: c#, filepath

I am making my first steps with C#. Taken over a project, and wondering why does the following code work:

```
Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ConfigTool.resources.bg.bmp");
```

I am wondering about the dots in the file path. Why is this okay? I would expect to see something like

```
Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ConfigTool\\resources\\bg.bmp");
```

Which is not working. So I am puzzled.
The directory structure for the record is:

```
\ConfigTool\reources\bg.bmp
\ConfigTool\bin\Debug\myApplication.exe
```

Comment: You could have *read* the documentation on [Manifest Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/Library/ms950960.aspx) which is linked to from the help page for `GetManifestResourceStream`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, true indeed... Was spending time on searching for 'while dots allowed instead of slashes in c# path', instead of taking a deep breath and hit F1 on the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the file structure at your disk is the same to package structure in project/application (it defines this structure). and the app gets resources from packages (in apps logic) not from files. this is why you use dot notification not slashes.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why.